`var a = new B(); a = new B(); a = new C();` shouldn't work...SOLVED
Sorry for the clickbait, but here's my situation;
I'm studying using this book called "徹底攻略Java SE 11 Silver問題集" which is a popular textbook for beginner java engineers in Japan looking to take the Java Silver test by Oracle.
Question 8 in the 2nd chapter basically asks whether the following would compile or not given that each are defined in a separate file.
The answer is that it wouldn't because a = new C(); is trying to convert from B to C, which are incompatible. B and C extend A, but that doesn't mean that they are compatible with each other.
I get that, and this does in fact not work in most of the environments I've tested it in.
However, I've defined each in their own file and run this in java 21.0.2 and it prints "C".
How could this be?
If the answer is "because polymorphism", then could someone elaborate pls...
Both ChatGPT and Copilot say it should work fine, though my textbook says that it shouldn't.


class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var a = new B(); 
        a = new C();
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}

class A {
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class B extends A{
    @Override
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("B");
    }
    
}

class C extends A{
    @Override
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("C");
    }
    
}


I tried the code in java 5, 8, 15, and 21.
in java 5, 8, 15, I only tried it with one file. this is because I was using the web compiler in Hackerrank's quizzes. with 21 I tried both.

no. you are re-assigning a variable. but I can assure you, you didn't try this code in Java 5. anyway, where do you assume there is multiple inheritance here? The only form of (near) multiple inheritance I'm aware of is by adding default methods in an implemented interface while also having a similar method in a superclass, but there is an order in which it'll use. also: don't rely on ai generators please. Did you try the code? Did it work?

How did you run this program? What command did you run?

I've just tried compiling this with JDK 21, with separate files, using javac A.java B.java C.java Main.java, and it failed (as expected) with an error of: "Main.java:4: error: incompatible types: C cannot be converted to B". So I can't reproduce the "non-error". Please give more details of how you're compiling and running the code.

Your book is correct. The variable a is inferred to be of type B (from the right-hand side), and C is not a B. I see the expected compiler error when trying this myself. When you tried this and it printed "C", are you sure you didn't write A a = new B(); instead of var a = new B();?

thanks for all the comments.
when trying in java 5, I changed var to B because I got a different error that suggested it didn't support the var inference feature. This is when it says B and C are not compatible.
I ran the program in both the "single-source-file execution" method and by actually compiling it by running javac Main.java and then java Main.
What Slaw and Jean-Baptiste Yunès say make sense and it was my error.
I hit command + Z a few times and I had typed A a = new B(); at some point, which was likely when it worked.
Apologies for the simple overlook.

Java is a strongly typed language, which means that the compiler strongly verifies if what you write is correct from the point of view of the types involved in expressions.
var is a Java≥10 feature, it is a type inference construction. Your code cannot compile in Java 5 or Java 8.
When you use var to declare a variable, the compiler infers the type of the variable by determining the type of the initialisation expression.
Thus:
var a = new B(); // initialisation expression has type B

So it is exactly the same as (but inferred by the compiler):
B a = new B();

When you write:
a = new C();

compiler considers this as an error as a C is not a B (do not be fooled by the name of the variable, its type is what matters here).
The only way to make these two lines correct is to type a whith a common super-type of B and C (the following is correct in all Java versions, it is called subtyping polymorphism):
A a = new B();
a = new C();

Note: cutting the code in different files does not change anything in Java (at least for the concern of this post).
Note: do not blindly rely on ChatGPT or Copilot.

Thanks, you're right, I did type A a = new B(); by accident.
I'll delete this post as it was a simple overlook on my behalf.
Edit: I read the documentation on what to do with silly questions and apparently deleting isn't the best. I'll edit instead.
